# Can component be used on element as an attribute in AngularJS 1.6?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components

AngularJS 1.6 documentation for **directives** states:

> $compile can match directives based on element names (E), attributes (A), class names (C), and comments (M).
>
> (...)
>
> The following demonstrates the various ways a directive (myDir in this case) that matches all 4 types can be referenced from within a template.
>
> ```
> <my-dir></my-dir>
> <span my-dir="exp"></span>
> <!-- directive: my-dir exp -->
> <span class="my-dir: exp;"></span>
> ```

Can you use **components** in the same way, adding them to HTML element by *attribute*? Because documentation for components always shows examples of comonents being used as *elements*.

To clarify, instead of having to write it like below and cluttering my markup with non-standard elements:

```
<component-name></component-name>
```

I'd like to be able to do something like that in my HTML:

```
<h1 component-name=""></h1>
```

Comment: Short answer, No, you can't use Components as Attributes or Classes.

Comment: The whole purpose of a component is that it can be used as a self-contained element. It is supposed to be non-standard element. It is a syntactic sugar for a directive. If you need a directive, use a directive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entire web is moving towards components. I wouldn't be concerned about "non-standard elements." At any rate, components are restricted to elements only. They cannot be used for Attributes. This is the primary use case for directives vs. components.

Components are provided specifically for creating HTML and augmenting it with view based behavior. Directives are now primarily for decorating HTML.